# How to send specific user ID from bot framework emulator v4?

Tags: botframework

I need to send a specific user ID from the bot emulator (https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator). I use this textbox (see on a picture below)

[image]

But nothing sent. There is absolutely another guid in activity.From.Id.

Is it possible to sent message from emulator with a specific user ID?

Comment: Are you running your bot purely locally? Or, are you connecting to direct line using a secret or token (and which)?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, if you are using Direct Line to generate a token from a secret and you specify user Id there (see attached code), then Emulator should favor **that** value over any value you pass in thru the Emulator settings.

In my personal testing, the User ID setting seems to be overriding any other pre-existing value.

It should be noted, however, that if you specify a User ID value in settings, you will need to close the tabbed conversation and start it anew by re-entering the messaging endpoint and AppId/AppPassword (or reconnecting to your .bot file, if used). Simply pressing "Restart conversation" will not cause Emulator to pickup the User ID setting.

Hope of help!

```js
// Listen for incoming requests.
server.post('/directline/token', (req, res) => {
  // userId must start with `dl_` for Direct Line enhanced authentication
  const userId = (req.body && req.body.id) ? req.body.id : `dl_${ Date.now() + Math.random().toString(36) }`;
  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${ process.env.directLineSecret }`
    },
    json: {
      user: {
        Id: `${ userId }`
      }
    }
  };
  request.post(options, (error, response, body) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode < 300) {
      res.send(body);
      console.log('Someone requested a token...');
    } else {
      res.status(500).send('Call to retrieve token from DirectLine failed');
    }
  });
});
```

[image]

[image]